# why comparing char variables twice is faster than comparing short variables once

Tags: c++, c, performance, assembly

I have thought one compare must be faster than two. But after my test, I found in debug mode short compare is a bit faster, and in release mode char compare is faster. And I want to know the true reason.

Following is the test code and test result. I wrote two simple functions, `func1()` using two char compares, and `func2()` using one short compare. The main function returns temporary return value to avoid compile optimization ignoring my test code. My compiler is GCC 4.7.2, CPU Intel® Xeon® CPU E5-2430 0 @ 2.20GHz (VM).

```
inline int func1(unsigned char word[2])
{
        if (word[0] == 0xff && word[1] == 0xff)
                return 1;
        return 0;
}

inline int func2(unsigned char word[2])
{
        if (*(unsigned short*)word == 0xffff)
                return 1;
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
        int n_ret = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; ++j)
                for (int i = 0; i < 70000; ++i)
                        n_ret += func2((unsigned char*)&i);
        return n_ret;
}
```

Debug mode:

```
          func1      func2
real    0m3.621s    0m3.586s
user    0m3.614s    0m3.579s
sys     0m0.001s    0m0.000s
```

Release mode:

```
          func1      func2
real    0m0.833s    0m0.880s
user    0m0.831s    0m0.878s
sys     0m0.000s    0m0.002s
```

func1 edition's assembly code:

```
        .cfi_startproc
        movl    $10000, %esi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L6:
        movl    $1, %edx
        xorl    %ecx, %ecx
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L8:
        movl    %edx, -24(%rsp)
        addl    $1, %edx
        addl    %ecx, %eax
        cmpl    $70001, %edx
        je      .L3
        xorl    %ecx, %ecx
        cmpb    $-1, -24(%rsp)
        jne     .L8
        xorl    %ecx, %ecx
        cmpb    $-1, -23(%rsp)
        sete    %cl
        jmp     .L8
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L3:
        subl    $1, %esi
        jne     .L6
        rep
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

func2 edition's assembly code:

```
        .cfi_startproc
        movl    $10000, %esi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L4:
        movl    $1, %edx
        xorl    %ecx, %ecx
        jmp     .L3
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L7:
        movzwl  -24(%rsp), %ecx
.L3:
        cmpw    $-1, %cx
        movl    %edx, -24(%rsp)
        sete    %cl
        addl    $1, %edx
        movzbl  %cl, %ecx
        addl    %ecx, %eax
        cmpl    $70001, %edx
        jne     .L7
        subl    $1, %esi
        jne     .L4
        rep
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: 1) was it consistently faster? or is this just a glitch? 2) show us the generated assembly code.

Comment: Um... those times are well outside the uncertainty of the measurement... also, debug builds (==no optimizations) don't have meaningful time/complexity profiles. Furthermore, the second function invokes undefined behavior, so it isn't even worth reasoning about.

Comment: You have to show the assembly code generated by the compiler in each case for any discussion of this topic to make sense. C code does not have intrinsic performance. (Technically, assembly code doesn't either without a target processor, but we'll assume a modern widely-available one)

Comment: those numbers are practically the same. a one off is subject to os switching etc.. run it a few hundred times at least.

Comment: Increase the number of loop iterations by 10x or 100x to bring out the timing difference.

Comment: @H2CO3 `func2()` does not intrinsically invoke undefined behavior (that I can see). It can be called in a standard-compliant way by passing it the conversion to `unsigned char *` of the address of an `unsigned short`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Which is not the case, since `&i` is an `int *`.

Comment: Please add your `main` function's code, the times you measured for the 100x case and your CPU type to your question. It seems that this won't be settled without those pieces of information. P.S. Happy Xmas to all of you!

Comment: What do you mean by "Debug" and "Release" mode? Can you post the flags passed to the compiler?

Comment: Why bother with profiling a debug build? That makes no sense to me

Comment: @paulm: a lot of companies ship debug builds to production... for them, it definitely makes sense.

Comment: Note that if you were using a big-endian machine (say SPARC or PowerPC), then your comparison would always be with zero.  You are passing a pointer to `int` — cast to `unsigned char *` — and then trying to treat it as `short *`.  At one level it doesn't matter; it works for your test code.  At another level, it does matter; your code certainly isn't portable.  I'm not sure about 'undefined behaviour'; I'm suspicious that you are invoking UB, but haven't concluded for sure that you are.

Answer (score 3):

In GCC 4.6.3 the code is different for the first and second pieces of code, and the runtime for the func1 option is noticeably slower if you run it for long enough. Unfortunately, with your very short runtime, the two appear similar in time.

Increasing the outer loop by a factor of 10 means it takes about 6 seconds for func2, and 10 seconds for func1. This s using `gcc -std=c99 -O3` to compile the code.

The main difference, I expect, is from the extra branch introduced with the && statement. And the extra `xorl %ecx, %ecx` doesn't help much (I get the same, although my code looks subtly different when it comes to label names).

Edit: I did try to come up with a branchless solution using `and` instead of a branch, but the compile refuses to inline the function, so it takes 30 seconds instead of 10.

Benchmarks run on:

```
AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 965
```

Runs at 3.4 GHz.

Comment: I test 10x outer loop, and the two function's cost time increase 10 times both, 8.35s and 8.79s.

Comment: Obviously then your processor runs differently to mine - not whether it's better to have one that runs the func2 version in 6 seconds or one that runs func1 in 8...

Comment: Since we are going down that path anyway, can you both update your posts with your CPU types?

Comment: I don't know what `and` is, but how about substituting `&&` with `&` as a first step towards branchlessness?

Comment: I suspect the branch predictor is a factor here.  If I change the first function to do a single byte compare (comment out the `&& word[1] == 0xFF`), I get the same timing between both functions on my Phenom II (same processor as Mats', actually).

Comment: Wow, if you really want to see things fall apart on the Phenom II, switch `word[0]` and `word[1]` in `func1`.  It blows up to 28 seconds on my box, vs. the 6 and 10 second numbers, and that's _with_ inlining.